# How to Set User login Windows Phone 8 using sqlite database?

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, sqlite

Hi i am using windows phone 8 app. i want to set existing user login, i can add user registration but i can't do user login my code is give below.

```
public partial class LoginPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    public static class dal
    {

        public static SQLiteAsyncConnection connection;
        public static bool isDatabaseExisting;

        public static async void ConnectToDB()
        {
            try
            {
                StorageFile storageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("Bestin.sqlite");
                isDatabaseExisting = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                isDatabaseExisting = false;
            }

            if (!isDatabaseExisting)
            {
                try
                {
                    StorageFile databaseFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("Bestin.sqlite");
                    await databaseFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
                    isDatabaseExisting = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    isDatabaseExisting = false;
                }
            }

            if (isDatabaseExisting)
            {

                connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Bestin.sqlite"), true);

            }
        }
    }

    private void Click_Login(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dal.ConnectToDB();
        var query = dal.connection.QueryAsync<Task>("SELECT * FROM Task Where Email=" + "\'" + txtEmailaddress.Text + "\'" + "and Password=" + "\'" + txtPassword.Password + "\'").Result;

        if (query == null)
        {
            // invalid Login credentials
        }
        else
        {
            // do login
        }
    }

}
```

I am using your code.I got error **The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so do this ....

```
public static class dal
{
    public static SQLiteAsyncConnection connection;
    public static bool isDatabaseExisting;

    public static async void ConnectToDB()
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFile storageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("Bestin.sqlite");
            isDatabaseExisting = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            isDatabaseExisting = false;
        }

        if (!isDatabaseExisting)
        {
            try
            {
                StorageFile databaseFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("Bestin.sqlite");
                await databaseFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
                isDatabaseExisting = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                isDatabaseExisting = false;
            }
        }

        if (isDatabaseExisting)
        {

            connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Bestin.sqlite"), true);

        }
    }
}
```

make a class like above code for your database connection and call this at your application startup like this dal.ConnectToDB();

then in your loginpage do like this...

```
private void Click_Login(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

   var query = dal.connection.QueryAsync<Task>("SELECT * FROM Task Where Email=" + "\'" + txtEmailaddress.Text + "\'" + "and Password=" + "\'" + txtPassword.Password + "\'").Result;

   if(query == null)
   {
     // invalid Login credentials
   }    
   else
   {
     // do login
   }
}
```

Comment: i used your code i got error :The name 'isDatabaseExisting' does not exist in the current context. this only error

Comment: i have updated my solution please add public static bool isDatabaseExisting; just below public static SQLiteAsyncConnection connection;

Comment: which one ? sqlite db file or sqlite dll file? i tried to add sqlite db file, i can't do that but database have stored values

Comment: i don't know how to add that file.

Comment: right click on your project explorer and then click add and select existing item and browse to your db file and add it..

Comment: i can't find out my db file

Comment: hi Sandeep i can added sqlite file into my project.now i can do user registration but valid used not login.

Comment: have you registered the user you are trying to login

Comment: i can't to login because if i click login button it will go to check db connection and exit out.it does not check any values.

Comment: dont do dal.connectdb in buttonclick write it in app.xaml.cs application launching method..  and then on button click write rest of code

Comment: i think this code does not take any effect [http://pastie.org/8074996](http://pastie.org/8074996)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this ..

```
        private void Click_Login(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH);
            var query = dbconn.QueryAsync<Task>("SELECT * FROM Task Where Email=" + "\'" + txtEmailaddress.Text + "\'" + "and Password=" + "\'" + txtPassword.Password + "\'").Result;

           if(query == null)
           {
             // invalid Login credentials
           }    
           else
           {
             // do login
           }
        }
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your replay, i tried your code i got error like:  The name 'dbconn' does not exist in the current context

Comment: how was dbconn working in your code given in question ??  
you must have declared it somewhere same will work here

or you can write like this
SQLiteConnection dbconn = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH);

Comment: already i declared dbConn: dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH); this is right?

Comment: i tried this command also (SQLiteConnection dbConn= new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH);) if use this i got error : 'SQLite.SQLiteConnection' does not contain a definition for 'QueryAsync' and no extension method 'QueryAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'SQLite.SQLiteConnection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: can you show me the exact code you are implementing ...
this will me to figure out the issue

Comment: Sorry make it SQLiteAsyncConnection dbconn
then 
connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "DB_NAME"), true);

Comment: can you please tell me the errors...
one more thing that are you creating a new table every time you navigate that page ?

Comment: not like that. i ask you directly.please help me i need to existing user login. how can i do? i am new for windows phone sqlite.

Comment: please don't mine if i asked anything wrong with you?please replay

Comment: its ok i have posted another solution please check and tell me if thats working or not

Answer (score 0):

Hi i got solution in my question..,

```
      using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH))
        {
            var existing = dbConn.Query<Userlist>("select * from Userlist Where Email=" + "\'" + txtEmailaddress.Text + "\'" + "and Password=" + "\'" + txtPassword.Text + "\'").FirstOrDefault();

            if (existing != null)
            {

                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Input.xaml?selectedItem=", UriKind.Relative));

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("invalid login");
            }
        }
```